# Python script generating a Python script - evaluation of generated code

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code

```
def SetSnmpOid(oid, snmpDataType, value):
    try:
        global SNMP_COMMUNITY
        global SNMP_HOST
        global SNMP_PORT

        cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

        # Send to first Telnet IP address, different port for SNMP
        dataType = "rfc1902." + snmpDataType
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.setCmd(
                cmdgen.CommunityData(SNMP_COMMUNITY, mpModel=0),
                cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((SNMP_HOST, SNMP_PORT)), 
                                           (oid + "." + str(0), dataType(value)))
```

which, when run, generates this error

```
File "H:/code/test_script.txt.py", line 105, in SetSnmpOid
    (oid + "." + str(0), dataType(value)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

and I'm certain that the error refers to `dataType` (which evaluates to `rfc1902.integer`, which is correct). The problem seems to be using it as a function call `dataType(value)` as part of a tuple.

If anyone is interested, I am trying to emulate the code found [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/set-v1-multiple-values.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with trying dynamically build a reference to a function.

You're wanting to create a `rfc1902.integer` object which gets passed as an argument to the `cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget`. The problem is, the value of `dataType` is a string, not a callable. Once all the code is evaluated, you end up with this:

```
'rfc1902.integer'(value)
```

when what you really want is this:

```
rfc1902.integer(value)
```

To get the callable, you have two options

1. [load it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071/2348587) using `getattr`
2. [load it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479840/2348587) using a dict "switch statement."