# 2D Array out of range when it shouldn't be?? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration, coordinates

I am running into an issue while I am iterating through my 2D array. I am going through my 4X3 grid and changing the requested coordinate from one character to another, rather "deleting"  'B' or 'W' and instead leaving nothing( the ' - ' character). I wont get into the niddy griddy of the code, but what I can say that I am currently working with this grid:

> ```
> B W B W         <= trying =>       A1 A2 A3 A4
> W B W B        to get these to     B1 B2 B3 B4
> B W B W        <=correspond=>      C1 C2 C3 C4
> ```

B = black game pieces
W = white game pieces

Here is a snip of code so you can see where I am going with it, then I will post what I want to happen.

> ```
> removeB = input("~BLACK Player, remove one of your 'B's by typing in the coordinance: ")
> print("")
> removeW = input("~WHITE Player, remove one of your 'W's by typing in the coordinance: ")
> print("")
> newgrid = copy_grid(board)
> for r in range(numrows):
>     for c in range(numcols):
>         if(removeB == 'A1'):
>             newgrid[r][c] = '-'
>         elif(removeB == 'A2'):
>             newgrid[r][c+1] = '-'
>         elif(removeB == 'A3'):
>             newgrid[r][c+2] = '-'
>         elif(removeB == 'A4'):
>             newgrid[r][c+3] = '-'
>         elif(removeB == 'B1'):
>             newgrid[r+1][c] = '-'
>    etc....etc...etc...'
>         if(removeW == 'A1'):
>             newgrid[r-1][c-1] = '-'
>         elif(removeW == 'A2'):
>             newgrid[r-1][c-1] = '-'
>         elif(removeW == 'A3'):
>             newgrid[r-1][c+1] = '-'
>         elif(removeW == 'A4'):
>             newgrid[r-1][c+2] = '-'
>         elif(removeW == 'B1'):
>             newgrid[r][c-1] = '-'
>      etc....etc...etc...
> ```

You will see that once I go into the 2nd if statement that I i change the formatting of the newgrid coordinate checking as far as index values. I did this for testing purposes as I now know that I receive the same error message for both methods. Hence my confusion.... Also, I know that I will run into an issue because inside both if/else statements, I am checking a location even if it is not that player's Color. I will get to this once I get the coordinates to cooperate.

Here is the output that I want when removeB= A1 and removeW = C4 :

> ```
>   - W B W   
>   W B W B
>   B W B -
> ```

Here is the error message :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
>   initial()
>   File "C:\Users\Ted\Desktop\Lab3.1Final.py", line 84, in initial
>   newgrid[r][c] = '-'
>   IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Line 84 is the line right after the very first if(removeB == 'A1') executes and it goes to change the value at the desired coordinates.

Please let me know if I should submit any other code pertaining to this question if it would help in providing the best answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you should look at the switch/case statement (at least, Python's version) as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but lets say they type in A4, the if statement doesn't seem to break so it will look through the first time and work, then it will look 3 more times, breaking each time because c (1,2,3,4) will first be 0 + 4 = 4 (good answer!) then the next look 1+4 = 5 (bad answer) and so on... Why is it in a loop at all here? I think it would be best to approach this in a whole new way (I can help farther in chat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about this much more simply:

```
In [1]: grid = [['B','W','B','W'],['W','B','W','B'],['B','W','B','W']]

In [2]: def show_grid(grid):
    ...:     print(*(" ".join(row) for row in grid),sep='\n')
    ...:     

In [3]: def delete_at_coordinate(grid,coordinate):
    ...:     row = ord(coordinate[0]) - 65
    ...:     col = int(coordinate[1]) - 1
    ...:     grid[row][col] = '-'
    ...:     

In [4]: removeB = 'A1'

In [5]: removeA = 'C4'

In [6]: show_grid(grid)
B W B W
W B W B
B W B W

In [7]: delete_at_coordinate(grid,removeB)

In [8]: delete_at_coordinate(grid,removeA)

In [9]: show_grid(grid)
- W B W
W B W B
B W B -
```