# How to make a switch statement for a QuerySet in Python

Tags: python, function, switch-statement, case

I have been reading a few posts about switch replacements such as:

- [What is the Python equivalent for a case/switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement)
- [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

But none of them seem to fit my need.

What I really want is something like this

```
def f(x):
     switch(x):
         case 'pk':
         return User.objects.get(pk=x)
         case: 'email':
         return User.objects.get(email=x)
```

Is there an easy way for this to be done?

Comment: What are you casing on, `x`???

Comment: How does a simple `if, elif, else` block not work? ANY case-statement is straight-forwardly translatable into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure of what you mean, but you could use dict unpacking like this:

```
def f(param, value):
    return User.objects.get(**{param: value})
```

So,

```
f('pk', key)
```

would return

```
User.objects.get(pk=key)
```

Answer (score 1):

As they say in one of the mentioned questions:

> The direct replacement is `if/elif/else`.

Here is an example that fits your case

```
def f(x):
    if x == 'pk':
        return User.objects.get(pk=x)
    elif x == 'email':
        return User.objects.get(email=x)
    elif x == 'address':
        return User.objects.get(address=x)
    else:
        raise ValueError("x must be 'pk', 'email' or 'address'")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def f(x):
 switch = {
          'pk':(lambda val:User.objects.get(pk=val))
          'email':(lambda val:User.objects.get(email=val))
 }
 try:
    return switch[x](x)
 except KeyError:
    return default
```

or

```
def f(x):
  if x in ("pk","email"):
    return User.objects.get(**{x:x})
  return default
```

Comment: imho, using lambdas, dict and try-except just add unnecessary complexity

Comment: Yes, this is over-engineered. Just use `if, elif, else`.

Answer (score 0):

**Define**

```
def custom_switch(value, cases={}, default=None):
    try:
        cases[value]()
    except KeyError:
        if default is not None: default()
```

**Usage**

```
x = 'email'
custom_switch(x, {
    'pk': lambda: User.object.get(pk=x),
    'email': lambda: User.object.get(email=x)
}, lambda: print('error!'))
```