# Blocking python code to do only certain tasks

Tags: python

Is there any way to make a python program that only runs certain parts of the whole program depending on what the user inputs, I’m new to python and programming in a whole.

Comment: yes there probably is.

Comment: You should give here a read - https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: its about the conditional statements in python try them

Comment: This might give you some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement

Answer (score 0):

Use an If-Else logic.

```
if input == something:  
   This part of Code  
elif input == something else:
   This part of code  
else:  
   Do nothing
```