# How to avoid 20+ if statements when applying function to pandas based on a city/location

Tags: python

Let's say I have some customer data. The data is generated by the customer and it's messy, so they put their city into either the city or county field **or both**! That means I may need to check both columns to find out which city they are from.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'name':['jim','jon'],
                  'city':['new york',''],
                    'county':['','los angeles']})

print(mydf)

  name      city       county
0  jim  new york             
1  jon            los angeles
```

And I am using an api to get their zipcode. There is a different api function for each city, and it returns the zipcode for the customer's address, e.g. `123 main stret, new york`. I haven't included the full address here to save time.

```
# api for new york addresses
def get_NY_zipcode_api():
    return 'abc123'

# api for chicago addresses
def get_CH_zipcode_api():
    return 'abc124'

# api for los angeles addresses
def get_LA_zipcode_api():
    return 'abc125'

# api for miami addresses
def get_MI_zipcode_api():
    return 'abc126'
```

Depending on the city, I will call a different api. So for now, I am checking `if city == x or county ==x, call api_x`:

```
def myfunc(row):

    city = row['city']
    county = row['county']

    if city == 'chicago' or county == 'chicago':

        # call chicago api
        zipcode = get_CH_zipcode_api()

        return zipcode

    elif city == 'new york' or county == 'new york':

        # call new york api
        zipcode = get_NY_zipcode_api()

        return zipcode

    elif city == 'los angeles' or county == 'los angeles':

        # call los angeles api        
        zipcode = get_LA_zipcode_api()

        return zipcode

    elif city == 'miami' or county == 'miami':

        # call miami api        
        zipcode = get_MI_zipcode_api()

        return zipcode
```

And I `apply()` this to the df and get my results:

```
mydf['result'] = mydf.apply(myfunc,axis=1)

print(mydf)

  name      city       county  result
0  jim  new york               abc123
1  jon            los angeles  abc125
```

I actually have about **30 cities** and therefore 30 conditions to check, so I want to avoid a long list of `elif` statments. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I found some suggestions from a similar stack overflow question. Such as creating a dictionary with `key:city` and `value:function` and calling it based on city:

```
operationFuncs = {
    'chicago': get_CH_zipcode_api,
    'new york': get_NY_zipcode_api,
    'los angeles': get_LA_zipcode_api,
    'miami': get_MI_zipcode_api
}
```

But as far as I can see this only works if I am checking a single column / single condition. I can't see how it can work with `if city == x or county == x`

Comment: What about first creating a column merging the city and county and then use this new column to use the suggested dict?

Comment: You can also use something like this: `func = operationFuncs[city] if city in operationFuncs.keys() else operationFuncs[county]`

Comment: or `key = city if city != "" else county`

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf['result'] = mydf.apply(lambda row : operationFuncs.get(row['county']) or operationFuncs.get(row['city']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement). You can just perform this operation twice for `city` and `county` and save the result in two different variables, for each zipcode respectively. You can then compare the results and decide what to do if they differ (I am not sure if this can be the case with your dataset).

Since the dictionary-lookup is in O(1) and I assume your `get_MI_zipcode_api()` isn't any more expensive, this will have no real performance-drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but you could use the dict approach and just call it twice, once on city and once on county. The second would overwrite the first but the same is true of your if block, and this would only be a problem if you had city='New York' county ='Chicago' for example which I assume cannot occur.

Or you could use the dict and iterate through it, this seems unnecessary though.

```
For key, fn in fdict:
    if key in (city,county):
        fn()
```

I'd do this join in SQL before reading in the data, I'm sure there's a way to do the same in Pandas, but I was trying to make suggestions that build on your existing research even if they are not the best.

Answer (score 0):

If it's guaranteed that the value will either be present in city or country & not in both, then you can merge both the columns together into one.

```
df['region'] = df['City'] + '' + df['Country']
```

Then create a mapping of region and pincode, instead of creating a mapping of city with api function. Since, there are only 30 unique values, you can once store the value of city with zipcodes rather than calling the zipcode functions each time, as making an api call is expensive.

```
mappings = {
'chicago': 'abc123',
'new york': 'abc234',
'los angeles': 'abc345',
'miami': 'abc456'}
```

Create a dataframe using this dictionary & then merge with the original dataframe

```
mappings_df = pd.DataFrame(list(mappings.items()), columns=['region', 'zipcode'])
df.merge(mappings_df, how='left', on='region')
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: "If it's guaranteed that the value will either be present in city or country & not in both"  -  unfortunately it could be in both also.

Answer (score 0):

You need a relation table which can be represented by a `dict`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['jim','jon'],
                  'city':['new york',''],
                    'county':['','los angeles']})

df['region'] = df['city']  + df['county']
table = {'new york': 'abc123', 'chicago': 'abc124', 'los angeles': 'abc125', 'miami': 'abc126'}
df['region'] = df.region.apply(lambda row: table[row])
print(df)
```

Output

```
  name      city       county  region
0  jim  new york               abc123
1  jon            los angeles  abc125
```

Comment: the zipcode abc123 is an example. if i have 200 new york addresses they can't all have zipcode abc123. maybe i didn't explain clearly sorry. the api will search the customer's address, and return their unique zipcode. i didn't include a full address here `123 main street, xyz, abc etc.` just to keep it simple.

Comment: @SCool you need to edit your question, for now, the question is solved literally.

Comment: @SCool if `city`  and `county` are both filled, is it guaranteed that they have the same value?

Comment: unfortunately not. This is messy user generated data. They could even put their phone number in there. However I have a list of roughly 30 location strings I am looking for. `if string x, do api_x ... if string y, do api_y`. I just need to search those two columns.

Comment: I'll add a new question with more detail tomorrow.