# Ask about python import through if/else

Tags: python

I am learning basic python. I use the basics of python for my java homework and built a menu with 3 options. 1st option is simple equation. 2nd option is quadratic equation. 3rd option is calculate electricity bill

```
print("1. simple equation")
print("2.  quadratic equation")
print("3. calculate electricity bill")
print("Choose")
x=int(input());
if(x>3):
    print("no update")
elif(x==1):
    import lab3_1
elif(x==2):
    import lab3_2
else:
    import lab3_3
```

my question is :
Do we have another way to build a menu without using if else?
Why import doesn't work in python's switch case?

Comment: Please use a descriptive title.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Python does not have `switch` statement

Comment: Make use of dict (which is Python's equivalent of Java's Map) and map input with desired functions. Which is way better than switch/case

Comment: [What is the Python equivalent for a case/switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11479816/1324033)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Python equivalent for a case/switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try below to import the required module.

```
mod_dict={1:'lab3_1', 2:'lab3_2' , 3:'lab3_3'
required_module=__import__(mod_dict[x])
```

Use required_module.operation() as your wish. For eg, `required_module.add()`, here the module will be imported under key word `required_module`.