# Python get @property.setter decorated method in a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, properties, switch-statement, decorator

In Python there is no switch/case. It is suggested to use dictionaries: [What is the Python equivalent for a case/switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479816/what-is-the-python-equivalent-for-a-case-switch-statement)

in Python it is good practise to use `@property` to implement getter/setter: [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)

So, if I want to build a class with a list of properties to switch so I can get or update values, I can use something like:

```
class Obj():                                                                                          
"""property demo"""                                                                                  

    @property                                                                                
    def uno(self):                                                                                              
        return self._uno                                                                                       
    @uno.setter                                                                                
    def uno(self, val):                                                                            
        self._uno = val*10                                                                                   

    @property                                                                                          
    def options(self):                                                                                        
        return dict(vars(self))
```

But calling

```
o=Obj()
o.uno=10 # o.uno is now 100
o.options
```

I obtain  `{'_uno': 100}` and not `{'uno': 100}`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Properties aren't included in `vars`, because they're not in the instance `__dict__`. You just see the backing attribute. But it's unclear to me what you mean by *"a list of properties to switch"*, so it's hard to say what the right implementation might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vars` is really  a tool for introspection, and gives you the local variables of the current space, or in a given object - it is not a good way to get attributes and variables ready for final consumption.

So, your `options` code must be a bit more sophisticated - one way to go
is to search the class for any properties, and then using `getattr` to get
the values of those properties, but using the `getter` code, and 
introspect the instance variables, to get any methods attributed directly,
but discard the ones starting with `_`:

```py
    @property                                                                                          
    def options(self):            
        results = {}
        # search in all class attributes for properties, including superclasses:
        for name in dir(self.__class__):
            # obtain the object taht is associated with this name in the class
            attr = getattr(self.__class__, name)
            if isinstance(attr, property):   
                # ^ if you want to also retrieve other "property like"
                # attributes, it is better to check if it as the `__get__` method and is not callable:
                # "if hasattr(attr, '__get__') and not callable(attr):"

                # retrieves the attribute - ensuring the getter code is run:
                value = getattr(self, name)
                results[name] = value
        # check for the attributes assigned directly to the instance:
        for name, value in self.__dict__.items():
            # ^ here, vars(self) could have been used instead of self.__dict__ 
            if not name.startswith("_"):
                results[name] = value

        return results
```

**about switch..case**

On a side note to your question, regarding the "switch...case" construction: please disregard all content you read saying "in Python one should use dictionaries instead of switch/case". This is incorrect.

*The correct construct* to replace "switch...case" in Python is the "if..elif..else". You can have all the expressiveness one does have with a C-like "switch" with a plain "if-else" tree in Python, and actually, go much beyond that, as the testing expression in `if...elif` can be arbitrary, and not just a matching value.

```
option = get_some_user_option()
if option == "A":
   ...
elif option == "B":
   ...
elif option in ("C", "D", "E"):
   # common code for C, D, E
   ...
   if option == "E":
        # specialized code for "E",  
else:
   # option does not exist.
   ...
```

While it is *possible* to use a dictionary as a call table, and having functions to perform actions in the dictionary values, this construct is obviously not a "drop in" replacement for a plain switch case - starting from the point that the "case" functions can't be written inline in the dictionary, unless they can be written as a lambda function, and mainly
the point that they won't have direct access to the variables on the function calling them.