# i want to add code that rejects any invalid answers

Tags: python, input, crash

```
#for project 2
# division

def divide(a, b):
    return (a / b)
    
# palindrome
 
def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

print("Select operation.")
print("1. Divide")
print("2. Palindrome")
print("3. Square root")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3): ")
    
    if choice == '1':
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
    
    elif choice == '2':
        def isPalindrome(s):
            return s == s[::-1]
        
        s = str(input("Enter word:"))
        ans = isPalindrome(s)
        if ans:
                print (s+" "+"is a palindrome.")
        else:
                print (s+" "+"is not a palindrome.")
    
    elif choice == '3':
        threenumber = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        sqrt = threenumber ** 0.5
        print ("The square root of " + str(threenumber) + " is " + "sqrt", sqrt)

    next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
    if next_calculation == "no":
        break

else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

When testing it myself, in the beginning, if I entered any other input rather than 1, 2, or 3, it would jump to the "next_calculation" function. I want it to say "That's not an option, silly." instead.
When I select 1 or 3 if I enter anything other than a number the program will stop. I want it to say "That's not a valid number, silly."
How do I do this?

Comment: Append an else-block to the if-elif-sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with continue to ignore the loop and return to the start after checking if the input is in your list of possible values

```py
if choice not in ('1', '2', '3'):
   print("Invalid input")
   continue
```

Put that after the input

Answer (score 0):

I'd add right after `choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3): ")`, this snippet:

```
while (choice not in ['1','2','3']):
    print("That's not a valid number, silly.")
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3): ")
```

In this way, you won't reach the end of the cycle unless you give a correct number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use Switch in this case, instead of if/elses.

Check out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479840/15102719)

Otherwise, @Icenore answer seems to be correct. Also, remember to correctly ident your code, your current `else:` code is being executed after your `while True:`