# is there anyway to make this code shorter without using if's, elif's, else's

Tags: python, list, python-turtle

Is there anyway to make this code better and shorter

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
commands = ["forward","left","forward","right"]
for i in commands:
   if i == "forward":
       t.forward(10)
   elif i == "left":
       t.left(90)
   elif i == "right":
       t.right(90)
```

there's more in the list on my code

i tried alot of things but they didnt work

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code (besides superficial formatting issues).

Comment: Welcome! If your code works, this is better suited on the Code Review stack.

Comment: You can use a dictionary that maps each command string to a function that implements the command. `if command in commands: commands(command)()`

Comment: "Shorter" should not be a goal.  You don't want wasteful code, but as a general rule, shorter code is more difficult to read and maintain.  Remember that code gets read many more times than it gets written.

Comment: @Barmar, or just use `getattr()`. Now, they can make `commands` list of lists/tuples like (command, steps).

Comment: what is the source of these lists of strings?

Comment: You could use switch case statements: [What is the Python equivalent for a case/switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479840/6771046)

Comment: @U880D The `match` statement is intended for structure matching, not equality.

Comment: @buran Only if the user interface commands are identical to the turtle methods.

Comment: Note that the parameters passed to the turtle methods are not universal so there is some care to take if using `getattr()` that might still require branching.

Comment: Please show the full code so it's clear exactly what needs to be abstracted. As shown, there's no reason not to simply use `t.forward(10)`, `t.left(90)`, and so forth on 4 separate lines, with no loops or lists.

Answer (score 2):

Though `lambda` functions are really intended to return a value we can leverage them here to assign an action to each command. Alternatively, one could define action methods explicitly.

```py
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
command_actions = {
    "forward": lambda: t.forward(10),
    "left": lambda: t.left(90),
    "right": lambda: t.right(90),
}

commands = ["forward","left","forward","right"]
for command in commands:
   command_actions.get(command, lambda: None)()

import time
time.sleep(2)
```